# Get decimal value when convert inches to meter, pound to kilogram

Tags: python, decimal

I want to get the results like this:
    100 pounds = 45.3592
    50 inches = 1.27 meters
How do I do it? 
This is my code:

```
name = 'X'
age = 25 
height = 50 
weight = 100 
eyes = 'Black'
teeth = 'White'
hair = 'Black'
meters = 0.0254 * float(50)
kilograms = 0.453592 * float(100)

print "Let's talk about %s." % name
print "She's %d inches tall." % height
print "She's %d pounds heavy." % weight
print "Actually that's too skinny."
print "She's got %s eyes and %s hair." % (eyes, hair)
print "Her teeth are usually %s depending on the coffee." % teeth

print "If I add %d, %d and %d I get %d." % (age, height, weight, age + height + weight)
print "An other way of saying, I am %d meters and %d kilograms." % (meters, kilograms)
```

---

---

Comment: Rather than `* float(50)` or `float(100)` you can simply use `50.0` and `100.0`

Comment: I spoke too soon - you can just use `50` and `100` because you're multiplying by a decimal constant (0.0254 and 0.453592)

Comment: it not working like that. That why I don't understand, I keep getting just 1 meters and 45 kilograms. It should be 1.27 and 45.3592

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `%d` to `%f`:

```
print "An other way of saying, I am %f meters and %f kilograms." % (meters, kilograms)
```

If you are looking to limit to 2 decimal places, then you can set `%.2f`:

```
print "An other way of saying, I am %.2f meters and %.2f kilograms." % (meters, kilograms)
```

Or, you can use `format`:

```
print "An other way of saying, I am {} meters and {} kilograms.".format(meters, kilograms)
```

Limiting to 2 decimal places using `format`:

```
print "An other way of saying, I am {:.2f} meters and {:.2f} kilograms.".format(meters, kilograms)
```

Take a look at the [string formatting operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Comment: ways to go! Thanks a lot. By the way, you help me learn new stuffs :))

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck @LINHHUYNH